# Allow a query string on htaccess to pass directly

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have the following setup which I have implemented on `.htaccess` already.

`https://example.com/` - Main Wordpress website
`https://example.com/forum` - SMF forum website

The forum website used to be on `https://example.com` earlier and I have moved it to `/forum` recently. So that old links such as `https://example.com/index.php?topic=29414.new;topicseen#new` works I have added the specific rules in the `.htaccess`. All this is working fine.

My problem is that on my WordPress website I have certain links which uses query strings, eg: `https://example.com/?et_fb=1` or `https://example.com/?preview=true` but these all get ignored or just go to the homepage now. These query string links are usually stuff like previewing a post, page builder link, etc. on the Wordpress site. Appreciate any help to sort this out.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /forum/index.php/$1 [L,R]
# if query string is present
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
# redirect "/index.php" to "/forum/index.php
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /forum/index.php [L,R]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "fbclid=" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that any URL with a query string is being sent to your `/forum`. In order to resolve the conflict you need to be more specific.

So, you either need to be selective and only send URLs that have specific query strings to your `/forum`, such as those starting `topic=`. Or, create exceptions and *not* send URLs that contain certain query strings (that relate) to WordPress_ to your `/forum`. Whichever is the lesser.

For example, only send URLs that contain `topic=` to your `/forum`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^topic=
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /forum/index.php [L,R]
```

Or, prevent URLs that contain `et_fb=` or `preview=` being sent to your forum (everything else is sent to your forum):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(et_fb|preview)=
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /forum/index.php [L,R]
```